# Altium Single Layer Mode - Vias Color

Tags: pcb-design, altium

After I last updated Altium, there has been a change of behaviour. When using single layer view, the vias now blend in color with the other tracks, which is sometimes confusing. Is this expected and can this be changed back from the settings?

Before:

[image: Before Altium Behaviour]

After:

[image: After Altium Behaviour]

Comment: If you can, please add the version of Altium you were using before and after the update (to help future visitors determine if this question applies to them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change was implemented in [Altium Designer 21.9](https://www.altium.com/documentation/new-in-altium-designer-version-21?version=21) and is called **Accurate Layer Drawing**.

> Accurate color usage in single-layer mode - switch to single-layer mode and the multi-layer objects are automatically displayed in the active layer color.

At the time of that update (Nov 2021), it was in Open Beta and could be turned off by disabling the `PCB.LayerDrawingOrder.ProperMultilayer` option in the Advanced Settings dialog.

As of the version I am running, 22.5.1, the option is still there:

[image: PCB.LayerDrawingOrder.ProperMultilayer option in advanced settings]

Personally, I find having vias displayed with the correct layer color in single-layer view mode preferable. One thing you may want to try before changing this setting: If you just want to be able to easily see vias while in single-layer view mode, change your selection filter to *only* vias, and Select All. This will highlight all vias in white. I use this to gauge whether, for example, there is an area of stitching or shielding that I have overlooked.

Comment: Thank you! I have been using it as is for a couple of months and I can see the appeal and I definitely don't want to completely get rid of it, just be able to toggle it from time to time depending on needs. Like you have mentioned, it is something useful to discern vias on large pours to see if it needs additional stiching.